# Redirect to another server - ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

Does anybody know how to redirect to another server/solution using ASP.NET MVC? Something like this:

```
public void Redir(String param)
{
   // Redirect to another application, ie:
   // Redirect("www.google.com");
   // or
   // Response.StatusCode= 301;
   // Response.AddHeader("Location","www.google.com");
   // Response.End();

}
```

I´ve tried both ways above, but it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RedirectResult` will give you a 302, however if you need a 301 use this result type:

```
public class PermanentRedirectResult : ActionResult
{
    public string Url { get; set; }

    public PermanentRedirectResult(string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("url is null or empty", "url");
        }
        this.Url = url;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 301;
        context.HttpContext.Response.RedirectLocation = Url;
        context.HttpContext.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Then use it like mentioned above:

```
public PermanentRedirectResult Redirect()
{
    return new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Source (as it's not my work): http://forums.asp.net/p/1337938/2700733.aspx

Comment: +1 for adding the source from where you got it. I can appreciate such act.

Answer (score 5):

```
    public ActionResult Redirect()
    {
        return new RedirectResult("http://www.google.com");
    }
```

hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1):

// It was not working in my case so I did some trick here.

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
{
     return new PermanentRedirectResult ("http://www.google.com");
}
```

Comment: It tries to redirect in the same domain, like www.mysite.com/Home/www.google.com. Can you add any clarification about this please?