# Different domain names pointing to subfolders in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure

Not sure if what I'm describing is possible, but if so I'd like to know how.

I have an ASP.NET Azure Shared mode website with a domain, lets say `mydomain.com` pointing to it. I have a shop there, which is currently at `mydomain.com/shop`.

What I'd like is to point a different domain, `myshop.com` to the page at `mydomain.com/shop`. Can I do that?

Comment: Can you provide some more details? Where exactly are you stuck, what have you tried, is there something specific blocking you?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the quickest approach would be [URL-Rewriting](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module), which is installed by default on Azure Website / WebRole.

Configuration can be made in the web.config -> [more details](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) although you I would imagine if you're using MVC there might a slightly more elegant [Routing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344530/redirect-to-another-server-asp-mvc), maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question right, but
you could use the [HttpResponse Redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4(v=vs.110)) from the .net framework in order to *redirect the response*.