# asp net mvc domain redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, redirect, subdomain, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a MVC web application and the url's are

**abc.xy.com** - for the rest of the world excluding China

**abc.xy.com.cn** - for China (.com doesn't work in China, so created this)

Everything is working fine with that, but I need something like:

If the user from China tries to load the url **abc.xy.com** then the application should redirect the request to **abc.xy.com.cn**

How can I achieve this domain redirection through the application.

Thanks in advance,

Amarnath.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Maxmind's free GeoIP database](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/) to check what country the client is in.
They have a C# API that should work well with MVC Application.

For code referance [check this URL](http://lukencode.com/2010/05/19/ip-to-geo-location-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: hi, thanks for reply and sorry if i am not posted the question correctly. We have webapi already to identify the country. I don't need that. What i need is is how can i achieve this domain redirection. Can i use mvc routing technique?

Comment: RedirectResult will help you. for more detail check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344530/redirect-to-another-server-asp-mvc) This gives you more guide line.